# Google Analytics Create Tracker "Auto" parameter

Tags: google-analytics, tracker

The default way to create a tracker is:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

If I want to create a secondary tracker, do I do:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', {'userId': 'testrr00'});
```

Or:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {'userId': 'testrr00'});
```

?

I've seen some documentation about what 'auto' parameter does. But between my working GA code vs my non working GA code, this is the only difference between them. One is using 'auto' parameter while doesn't have userid parameter, and the other is having userid parameter, but doesn't use 'auto' parameter. I'm just curious if it's because of the omitting of 'auto' parameter that makes my GA code is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply repeating the create call will not create a second tracker, it will overwrite the first. You need a named tracker, which can be created both by

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto', 'T1000');
```

or

```
ga('create', {trackingId: 'UA-XXXX-Y', cookieDomain: 'auto', name: 'T1000'});
```

You need to include a name, either passed as parameter in the correct position or as key/value pair in a configuration object. You then address your second tracker by name

```
ga('T100.send', 'pageview');
```

The relevant sentence from the documentation is probably:

> ga('create', ...) can accept both position arguments and object
>   arguments for the trackingId, cookieDomain and name fields. Order is
>   important.

I.e. if you do positional parameters the cookie domain is expected after the Account ID, so this needs to be either "auto", "none" or the correct domain name, else GA will not set cookies and will not work.

Comment: Oh, okay then, I'll assume the default 'auto' parameter and not messing up with the cookies. Thanks for crash course on the cookiedomain and parameters list.